# Pattern in which there are spaces dividing the number block diagonally

Tags: java

I need this kind of a pattern :

```
 1234

5 678

91 23

456 7
```

where the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,....... are given

I have tried the following:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Array_pat1

{

static void main()throws IOException

{
    System.out.println("Please enter the dimensions of 2 dimensional arrays : ");

    int d= input.Int();


    int sum=0,prod=1;
    int a[][]=new int[d][d];
    
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<d;k++)
            a[i][k]=input.Int();
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
        
        for(int j=i;j<d;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

but the output is like:

```
1234 

 678

  23

   7
```

I think the other half of the number block is missing due to some small errors. Where is the problem?

Comment: i am changing it ,sorry

Comment: What happened when you stepped through this with a debugger, or at least a piece of paper and a pencil? Where does the program's execution differ from what you would expect?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: i want to print the numbers in the given pattern by an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
    }        

    System.out.print(" ");

    for(int j=i;j<d;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: well debugged! got my mistake